# Getting list for all level children for a given level

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
id_page | id_parent | title
-----------------------------
    1         0         sth1
    2         1         asd
    3         1         qwe
    4         2         are
    5         4         gds
    6         5         lkj
    7         4         nmn

- 1
---- 2
--------- 4
------------- 5
------------------6
--------------7
---- 3
```

What I am trying to achieve is get a single level array of all sub children for a given id_page. There is no limit in depthness.

For id_page 2, I should get `array(4,5,6,7)` or for id_page 4, i should get `array(5,6,7`)

I am bit lost, appreciate any help.

Comment: I hope you consider that from id_page 2 should be array(4) and from id_page 4 => array(5,7) ?

Comment: @DaHaKa corrected but what I need is: 2 should return all relatives (like family tree) as 4,7,5,6.. So 4 should return 5,6,7

Comment: That's illogical or I can't understand question ...

Comment: It's quite logical. He wants to get all of the children with deepness.

Comment: I would suggest fetching the table, building the tree structure in php, and then use depth-first-search to find all the children.

Comment: @tftd I built an array with php that rebuilds flat results to children indexed multi-dimensional array. How should I proceed?

Comment: @atomman I already have children indexed array. How to go with depth-first-search?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search),  to see how to use the algorithm. Without seeing your datastructure I'm not going to speculate.

Comment: In your question you've shown an example that implies you're using a database. Can you give us an example with the array and php code you currently have?

Comment: @atomman  Here is what I have done at php: http://pastebin.com/jqFHGPBe

Comment: @YahyaE Added my inital thoughs as an answer now, let me know how it works out. And bare in mind, none of the code is tested at all, but as stated, the basic concepts are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this](http://pastebin.com/jqFHGPBe) exampel you should be able to use something like this:
(Ps: None of this is testes, but the basic flow show be correct)

```
$root_id = 2;
$stack = array();
$childList = array();

array_push($stack, $root_id);

while (count($stack) > 0) {
  $current = array_pop($stack); // Depth first search
  //$current = array_shift($stack); //Breadth first search


  //array_push($stack, $treearr[$current]['children']); Maybe?? Something you'll have to check
  //array_push($childList, $treearr[$current]['children']); 


  for ($treearr[$current]['children'] as $child) {
    array_push($stack, $child);
    array_push($childList, $child);
  }
}
```

The `childList` should contain all children found beneath `root_id`.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the database organization is incorrect. 
With your current database structure you'll be able to get only one level of depth. 
Meaning `SELECT * FROM pages WHERE parent_page_id = 1`. This will give you the children of `page_id=1`. If any of those children also have children, you'll need to do `SELECT * FROM pages WHERE parent_page_id = the_child_id` for each child.

That would be insufficient resource usage. I would suggest you try using a model similar to [this one](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/).
It will allow you to get all children of a parent with one query.

Comment: For now I don't have this chance. I built an array with php that rebuilds flat results to children indexed multi-dimensional array. How should I proceed?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you currently have done in php?